# Prove that the transpose of a symplectic matrix is also symplectic

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symplectic-linear-algebra

I worked out with symplectic matrices that the transpose is also symplectic for the $2\times 2$ case since the algebra was easy and the determinant of the matrix just needed to equal $1$. [The expression for determinant is easy for $2\times 2$ matrices.] and the transpose has equal determinant. But what about the $n\times n$ case. Is it also true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $S$ is symplectic of size $2n\times 2n$, i.e., satisfies $S^TJS=J$, so is $S^T$. To see this, take the inverse of the equality $(S^{−1})^T JS^{-1}= J$ (because if $S$ is symplectic, then $S^{-1}$ is symplectic too).

Comment: What do you mean by take the inverse of the equality?

Comment: I mean, taking the inverse on both sides, e.g., if the equation is $C=DE$ then taking the inverse gives $C^{-1}=E^{-1}D^{-1}$, right ?

Comment: Ah I understand, thank you.

Comment: Thank you! You helped me get unstuck today!

Comment: Here $J$ is supposed to be the matrix of some non-degenerate skew-symmetric bilinear form with respect to some basis of a $2n$-dimensional real vector space. Then how can you even conclude that $J^{-1} = J^{\top}\ $? I have no idea.